# RVM: how to change default path to home directory?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I got this error on using RVM

```
kithokit@14:22:59 ~ $ rvm install 1.9.3
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448’: Permission denied
Could not detect ruby version/name for installation, please be more specific.
```

How can i change the default directory to /home/kithokit/.rvm

Comment: @majioa: ya it was good thanks! But i have updated my answer which is more specific to what the question needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the trace by executing this script

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/groupdel rvm
/bin/echo "RVM is removed. Please check all .bashrc|.bash_profile|.profile|.zshrc for RVM source lines and delete
or comment out if this was a Per-User installation."
```

coming from https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting#sudo

make sure to restart machine to get rid of any environment variables that would point out to the old location (yes it is required in case of playing with system installation).